# Fetch Keys from Response Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

Sending Client request to get data from API.

```
request =client.get_income('ET',incomeType='PNL',startTime=1611287550000)
```

The API returns the following data:

```
[{"symbol":"ET","incomeType":"R","income":"-2.4","time":1611287909000,"info":"50538270"},{"symbol":"ET","incomeType":"R","income":"1.68","time":1611287909000,"info":"50538271"}]
```

It's a dictionary inside the list. When I try to access the items through a for loop or any of the following methods, It returns the OBJECT.

Methods I tried:

```
for item in request:
    print(item['income'])

returns this : <model.income.Income object at 0x000000684EFB4580>
```

```
print(request[0]['income']
ERROR: TypeError: 'Income' object is not subscriptable
```

None of them works.

Comment: Expected output is all keys from the response dictionary??

Comment: 'income' key specially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it myself.

```
request =client.get_income('ET',incomeType='PNL',startTime=1611287550000)

for x in range(len(request)):
    print(request[x].__dict__['income'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
request = [{"symbol":"ET","incomeType":"R","income":"-2.4","time":1611287909000,"info":"50538270"},{"symbol":"ET","incomeType":"R","income":"1.68","time":1611287909000,"info":"50538271"}]

for item in request:
    print(item['income'])
```

it's working fine on my pc, I'm using python 3.9

```
-2.4
1.68
```

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you have is a JSON. Use Pandas to parse it and access it elements:

```
import pandas as pd

request = [{"symbol":"ET","incomeType":"R","income":"-2.4","time":1611287909000,"info":"50538270"},
       {"symbol":"ET","incomeType":"R","income":"1.68","time":1611287909000,"info":"50538271"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(request)
print(df)
print(f'Incomes are: {df["income"].tolist()}')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Request is a client object: request =client.get_income('ET',incomeType='PNL',startTime=1611287550000) 

It returns the data which can be printed, Even the PD Dataframe not works.

0  <binance_f.model.income.Income object at 0x000...
1  <binance_f.model.income.Income object at 0x000...
KeyError: 'income'

Comment: I have printed the dataframe in my response. It works.